# How to modify this code to use serial event to act after carriage return?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

In part of a code used with UNO, I want to send number A and number B at once as A,B to the Arduino board if there is carriage return. So at the moment in HyperTerminal when I type: 100,0.5 the Arduino board immediately reacts x becomes 100 and n becomes 0.5. Following parts are related to reading with serial event:

```
void loop() {

      if (stringComplete){ 

      delay(1000);
      Mwrite(level);
      sendFrequency(n); 
      delay(100);  

      stringComplete = false;   

   } 
}
```

and in serial event:

```
void serialEvent() {  

     while (Serial.available()) {

     slevel  = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
     Serial.read(); //next character is comma, so skip it using this
     x = Serial.readStringUntil(',');

     level = slevel.toInt();
     n = x.toDouble();
     stringComplete = true;  
  }  
}
```

But what I want to do is, I want the board only read the serial data only if I hit carriage return. So I should type 100,1 and then I should also hit carriage return for Arduino to react to the serial data.

How can this code be modified to achieve that?

Comment: Forget `serialEvent()`. It's something Arduino should *never* have included in the API. It's an idiotic function that has no purpose in reality. Putting the content of `serialEvent()` in `loop()` is exactly the same (and often far more convenient).

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: The SerialMonitor does not send anything until you press "Send". It's a good idea to choose `newline` as additional delimiter character when sending. In addition to Majenko's  readline:  There's a strtok function you might want to use

Comment: set the terminal to send on Enter, not every character. btw. readStringUntill removes the terminal character from receive buffer. and shouldn't your second readStringUntil read until '\n'?

Comment: @Majenko, no it's not idiotic, it's just misunderstood. I'll admit it has limited use-cases, but it can be a big help. For instance, it helped a ton when designing my [RC airplane library](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/ArdUAV)

Comment: The concept may have merit, but the implementation is idiotic. Now if they'd hooked it into the RX interrupt then it may have been useful. As it is, it's idiotic. And I stand by that word.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can solve it. The easiest way to do it is by just adding one more line in your code.

```
static bool stringComplete = false;
String x;
String slevel;
static int level;
static int n;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (stringComplete)
  {
    Serial.println(level);
    Serial.println(n);   
    stringComplete = false;   
  } 
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    slevel  = Serial.readStringUntil(',');

    //Serial.read(); // <-- You don't need this line. readStringUntil() will read ','

    x = Serial.readStringUntil(',');

    level = slevel.toInt();
    n = x.toDouble();
    Serial.readStringUntil('\r'); // <--------- Add this line
    stringComplete = true;  
  }  
}
```

But this is not probably the right way to do it. First, ***serialEvent()*** executes in between ***loop()*** i.e. this is what it looks like:

```
while(1)
{
    loop();
    serialEvent();
}
```

So, it is not like that the function will get called during a serial event. It just gets executed right after ***loop()***. Also ***readStringUntil()*** has a timeout (default: 1s). So if your 'until' character doesn't show up within one second of the function call, it will return with whatever it has. To test this, just type one character on your HyperTerminal and wait at least for a second, and see the output.

Ideally, this is how you should handle the serial's incoming byte:

- Check if there is serial byte available to read
- If there is, read one byte and save it in a buffer/string. (I'm not really a fan of **String** variables, but in the example, I will use String because you were using a **String**)
- If the byte you just read is delimiter (e.g. CR or '\r'), indicate the main loop that string is complete.
- In the main loop parse the whole string.

So this is how the code looks like with above-mentioned points:

```
static bool stringComplete = false;
String x;
String slevel;
static int level;
static int n;
String rxString = "";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (stringComplete)
  {
    // Parse the rxString
    int index1 = rxString.indexOf(',');             // finds location of first ,
    slevel = rxString.substring(0, index1);         // captures first data String
    int index2 = rxString.indexOf(',', index1 + 1); //finds location of second ,
    x = rxString.substring(index1 + 1, index2);     //captures second data String

    level = slevel.toInt();
    n = x.toDouble();

    Serial.println(level);
    Serial.println(n);  

    // Reset the string
    rxString = ""; 
    stringComplete = false;   
  } 
}

void serialEvent()
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the rxString:
    rxString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a carriage return, indicate main loop
    if (inChar == '\r') 
    {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }  
}
```